# MobileFirst application preview failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am developing an mobile application using IBM mobile first and it works fine in my local.now I migrated the code to production environment with WAS and mobile first 7.0 installed. when I try to open the application url i am getting the below error.

```
[http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/authorization/v1/clients/preview] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.
http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/apps/services/preview/EPSML/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js Line 5129

[/Thinkmatix/apps/services/api/EPSML/common/heartbeat] failure. state: 404, response: undefined
http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/apps/services/preview/EPSML/common/0/default/worklight/worklight.js Line 5129
```

And below is my debug info

```
Request [/Thinkmatix/apps/services/api/EPSML/common/heartbeat]
worklight.js (line 5129)
Request [http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/authorization/v1/clients/preview]
worklight.js (line 5129)
Request [http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/authorization/v1/clients/preview]
worklight.js (line 5129)
Client registration failed with error: {"status":404,"responseHeaders":{"X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Content-Language":"en-US","Content-Length":"0","Connection":"Close","Date":"Thu, 25 Jun 2015 21:13:58 GMT"},"responseText":"","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.","invocationContext":null}
worklight.js (line 5129)
Failed to send heartbeat
```

please find the logs below

```
[6/25/15 20:13:37:166 GMT] 0000008e DMAdapter     I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.DMAdapter getAnalysisEngine FFDC1009I: Analysis Engine using data base: /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/logbr/ffdc/adv/ffdcdb.xml
[6/25/15 20:13:37:193 GMT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_a76ee39e_15.06.25_20.13.37.1424049846352496539608.txt com.ibm.ws.security.token.WSCredentialTokenMapper.createPropagationTokenBeforeAuthenticatedCallerSet 1691
[6/25/15 20:13:37:204 GMT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_a76ee39e_15.06.25_20.13.37.1942014134630567982878.txt com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getSubjectFromDynaCacheOrOriginatingServer 1919
[6/25/15 20:13:37:216 GMT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_a76ee39e_15.06.25_20.13.37.2068488313294570014924.txt com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login 3683
[6/25/15 20:13:37:335 GMT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_a76ee39e_15.06.25_20.13.37.2166619601795812867033.txt com.ibm.ws.security.web.WebAuthenticator.validate 2952
[6/25/15 20:13:37:338 GMT] 0000008e RequestProces I org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) with message 'null' while processing GET request sent to http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/authorization/v1/clients/preview

[6/30/15 9:21:08:406 GMT] 00000098 LTPAServerObj W   SECJ0371W: Validation of the LTPA token failed because the token expired with the following info: Token expiration Date: Tue Jun 30 07:15:00 GMT 2015, current Date: Tue Jun 30 09:21:08 GMT 2015 Token attributes:  port=8880, username=user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/uid=wasadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm, hostname=dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com.. This warning might indicate expected behavior. Please refer to technote at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594981.
[6/30/15 9:21:08:412 GMT] 00000098 RequestProces I org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) with message 'null' while processing POST request sent to http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/authorization/v1/clients/preview
```

Any suggestions as how I can rectify this error.

Comment: Do you have the application deployed to the production environment?  I mean, not just the WAR file and the runtime, but did you deploy the WLAPP files to the production server too?  Can we see the complete server log that shows the failure?

Comment: Yes the application wlapp and adapters are deployed and the home screen gets loaded after that only it is giving this error.

Comment: So you are trying to preview your application on MFP 7 server by clicking "Preview"? and you get the error.!

Comment: Not by clicking on preview button as the preview button is not enabled in MF. I just tried with the web url and got this error

Comment: And where do you get this "web url" from?

Comment: Are you trying to do a device-specific preview (such as preview as iPhone, Android, etc.)?  On a production server, only common resources preview is supported.

Comment: Pat, you can copy the URL in the question. It happens in preview.

Comment: The person who installed the server gave me that url..

Comment: You want me provide that url here ?

Comment: The common resource preview URL should look something like:  http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/apps/services/preview/EPSML/common/0/default/index.html.  If you access the common  resource preview from the MobileFirst Operations Console, you'll get the right URL (sorry for the formatting of the URL here, Stack Overflow is doing that itself....).

Comment: You mentioned before that the preview button is not enabled - I'm not aware of any way to disable the common resource preview, so not sure where you are looking.  If you go into the Operations Console, select this runtime, and then click on "Applications" and then the application's name, you should see a list of the deployed environments, and the common resource preview button below that.  I'd be curious to know if you are seeing something different than that.

Comment: In MF 7.0 the preview button has been disabled... If you see the preview option then you haven't applied the proper fix pack and you need to apply so that it will disable the preview button.. And yes  the url will look like something you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

My current working assumption is this:

It's not only that the preview button is removed in a non-development environment (as you have confirmed in the comments), it's also the preview *component* that is not available. Simply put, there is *no preview* of applications in a QA/production environment and so if you are *forcing* a preview in an environment that does not *support* preview, I would say it is Expected that it is "failing" for you.

Comment: Ok now how can I test if my application is working fine or not in web ?

Comment: Add the Mobile Web or Desktop Browser environments. These are the supported environments for "web". They provide URLs to use.

Comment: so you mean to say if I hit this url http://dst14lp15.boulder.ibm.com:9080/Thinkmatix/apps/services/preview/EPSML/common/1.0/default/index.html which like a preview option it will fail?

Comment: There were no logs other than the logs that I provided above . When I debugged the page with firebug I got the above logs .. Heartbeat error

Comment: Is there any document for adding a device

Comment: I did some more research after seeing Idan's comments and your previous comments.  You're right about the fix pack - the preview button was removed for production environments with APAR PI37266 (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI37266) starting with build IF20150329-1858 (and the server I have been testing on is running a previous build).  It was removed because the preview servlet had indeed been removed, as Idan indicated.  Preview was never actually intended to be used on production servers, only in development environment.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add an web browser or a mobile browser to the device menu.Is there any documentation for this? @patbarron

Comment: Sure - just add it in Studio the same way you would add any other environment to you app (such as iPhone, Android, etc.).  Then rebuild and redeploy the app.  Desktop Browser and Mobile Web are available as environments you can add.

Comment: I have added the desktop browser and still I get the same error. My application was not able to connect to the database as well.

Comment: In the SQL adapter it is giving error code as 404 and there is no error description @patbarron